# How does Google keep web history?

Tags: google-search

Say I search for something in Google and click on a few results. After some time, if I again search for same thing, the search results show the earlier clicked links with different colours and date/time of visit. And, I know that this is associated with my Google account and not with the computer as such.

I had in mind that after the search, Google returns us with a page and clicking on those search results does not go through Google. So how does Google keep the web history?

Comment: Google doesn't let people directly to page they found. You go through google servers.

Comment: @Beniamin Sometimes they choose to insert a redirect for QA purposes. But for most users most of the time that's not true.

Comment: @oleschri - I don't know what they do if you're not logged in or not using web history, but I'm always logged in and I'm using web history and they always redirect through their servers. That way I have web history without google toolbar I guess. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Beniamin I have to apologize, you are right. Google seems to have changed their behavior since I last checked. In 2009 they started to redirect by default to get more precise click-through statistics: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/04/upcoming-change-to-googlecom-search.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A basic description of how Google Web History works:
http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54068

> [...]
>
> **Note:** Depending upon whether or not you're signed in to a Google
>   Account when you search, the
>   information we use for customizing
>   your experience will be different:
>
> **Signed-in personalization:** When you're signed in, Google personalizes
>   your search experience based on your
>   Web History. If you don't want to
>   receive personalized results while
>   you're signed in, you can turn off Web
>   History and remove it from your Google
>   Account. You can also view and remove
>   individual items from your Web
>   History.
>
> **Signed-out personalization:** When you're not signed in, Google
>   customizes your search experience
>   based on past search information
>   linked to your browser, using a
>   cookie. Google stores up to 180 days
>   of signed-out search activity linked
>   to your browser's cookie, including
>   queries and results you click.

To change Web History settings for your account go to:
https://www.google.com/history/

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article that attempts to explain how Google Web History works, primarily from a user experience standpoint:  http://searchengineland.com/google-search-history-expands-becomes-web-history-11016

Does this answer your question, or are you looking for something more technical?

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight the links on a Google search, you will see an URL starting with `http://google.com/url?url=`. This is where they see what you surf. Strangely, this does not always happen, maybe because they can catch it with JavaScript too.